# How can I add progress bar to my github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I am writing some GitHub actions for my project and I would like to have the orange progress bar to track the progress of my action.

[image: example of github action doc]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The progress bar is shown on jobs that define the [attribute `environment`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#using-an-environment)

Here's an example of how to use it:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: Production
    steps:
      - run: ./deploy.sh --env prod
```

Comment: thank you I managed to display a progress bar

But it always fills up instantly 
is it because my steps are too fast or is it because i am still missing something ? 
I would like to see it filling up

@rethab

Comment: I'm not sure how GitHub determines the speed of the progress bar. Perhaps you could try adding several steps to the job or some sleep command to experiment?

Comment: so odd that a progress bar is only displayed when the job is meant to be a deployment. Those should be separate things.

Answer (score -3):

This is workflow reuse, you can read more in the documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows)

This progress bar shows jobs running in another workflow, which is probably not a good practice, but if you want this progress bar, you need to create various workflows and a centralized workflow that "reuses" all.

Github Actions show `jobs` running and done, you can track this why, no need for a progress bar. If you really want a progress bar directly for track jobs, you need to ask Github for this feature.

Comment: the progress bar has nothing to do with reusable workflows